# $lookup operator has failed to return the combined data from multiple collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I don't why my aggregate pipeline has failed to combine the multiple collections(comments and users). I am trying to return the username for each userId in the comments collections.
MongoDB version.... v3.0.7

```
.get(function(req,res){
      //returning aggregate values from comments part.. comment.authorId must hv user.username.
       CardComment.aggregate([ //stackoverflow qn... ask tomorrow  show the models
           //now perform the mongo join  of multiple collections like in SQL Joins
           {
             $lookup:{
                from: 'users', //external collection.
                localField: 'authorId', //input field., from current collection.. cardComments
                foreignField: '_id', //foreign key from external collection,
                as: 'commentUser'
             }
           },
           //filter according to the cardId.. part. find()... first pipeline
           {
             $match:{"card": req.params.cardId }
           }

       ], function(err,comments){
         if (err) {
            res.json({"success":false, "message": 'Error in loading comments'})
         } else {
             //res.json({"success": true, "message": comments})
              console.log(JSON.stringify(comments))
            //console.log(comments) //u need to ask for help on stackoverflow.
         }
       })

    })
```

for my MongoDB schemas using mongoose module,
i have shortened it to make the question smaller.
cardComments collection schema

```
authorId:{
      type: ObjectId,
      ref : 'User',
      required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
       type: Date,
       default: Date.now
    }
```

then for the users collection.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
username: { type: String, required: true, lowercase: true, index: { unique: true } },
email: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
//password: { type: String, required: true }  u forgot the select field.. that z why login was disturbing
 password: {type: String, select: false} //that z why u need postman to test stuff
});
```

I am interested in showing the username field from users collection in the part of the authorId of the comments collection.
thank you

Comment: Failed how? No results? Does the `$lookup` fail or the `$match` fails? Have you checked to be sure that `userId` is actually the same type as `_id` in the foreign collection ( typically both need to be `ObjectId` ). The most common mistake is that one is stored as a "string" and the other is an `ObjectId`.

Comment: is `card ObjectId` in your `comment` schema ?

Answer (score 0):

As shown your schema you have used `ObjectId` it should be mongoose objectId like `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`. Then `$lookup` should work. and another thing if `cardId` is also `ObjectId` then you have to convert it as mongoose `ObjectId` to use in `$match` stage. And if `cardId` is in your `comments` schema then you should use `$match` stage first for performance issue.

so your model should be like

```
authorId:{
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
  ref : 'User',
  required: true
}
```

and your function

```
get(function (req, res) {
  // if cardId is ObjectId type
  let cardId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.cardId);
  CardComment.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {"card": cardId}
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'users',
        localField: 'authorId',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'commentUser'
      }
    }
  ], function (err, comments) {
    if (err) {
      res.json({"success": false, "message": 'Error in loading comments'})
    } else {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(comments))
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  as @Neil Lunn had noted  that i should inspect the error message which i inspected and it seems it is database version problem. $lookup is not supported in mongodb 3.0.7.   this is the error i got when i inspected it.{
    "success": false,
    "message": {
        "name": "MongoError",
        "message": "exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$lookup'",
        "errmsg": "exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$lookup'",
        "code": 16436,
        "ok": 0
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your efforts  as i inspected the error message for the $lookup operator.Thanks for the advice.  as @Neil Lunn had noted  that i should inspect the error message which i inspected and it seems it is database version problem. $lookup is not supported in mongodb 3.0.7.   this is the error i got when i inspected it.

```
{
"success": false,
"message": {
    "name": "MongoError",
    "message": "exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$lookup'",
    "errmsg": "exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$lookup'",
    "code": 16436,
    "ok": 0
}
```

}